# Accessing another classes member

Tags: c++

I have the following

```
class book
{
    friend class linkedList;
private:
    class student
    {
        friend class book;
        string name;
        string number;
        string gpa;
        student *left;
        student *right;

        student(string name1, string number1, string gpa1,
            student *left1 = NULL, student *right1 = NULL)
        {
            name = name1;
            number = number1;
            gpa = gpa1;
            left = left1;
            right = right1;
        }
    };

    int count;
    student *root;
    ofstream recordBook;

    void _add(student *&, string, string, string);
    void _display_book(student *);
    bool _search_for_name(string, string&, string&);
    bool _edit_entry(string &name, string &edited_number);
    void _del_person(student *&, string);
    void _save(student *root);
    void _del_Tree(student *);

public:
    student *currentRoot;
    book(void); //Constructor
    ~book(void);//Destructor
    void add(string entry_name, string telephone_number, string gpa);
    void display_book();
    bool search_for_name(string find_name);
    bool edit_entry(string entered_name, string edited_number);
    void del_person(string entry_name);
    void save();
    void load_data();
};

class linkedList 
{
    friend class book;
    int someInt;
    struct node 
    {
    public:
        string key;
        node *link;
        node *link2;
    } *pointer;
public:
    student book::*currentRoot = &book::currentRoot;
    linkedList();
    ~linkedList();
    void append(string &str);
    void del(string &str);
    void display();
};
```

And I need to make a pointer to "student *currentRoot" from my linkedList classes function.

```
void linkedList::append(string &str)
{
    node *q, *t;
    if(pointer == NULL)
    {

        pointer = new node;
        pointer->key = str;
        pointer->link = NULL;
        pointer->link2 = currentRoot;
        someInt += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        q = pointer;
        while(q->link != NULL)
        {
            q = q->link;
        }
        t = new node;
        t->key = str;
        t->link = NULL;
        q->link = t;
        someInt += 1;
    }
}
```

In linkedList::append I need to make link2 point to where currentRoot is pointing to. How can I do this? (currentRoot is already set to point at a node in a binary tree. Just gotta get my hash table to also point there.) Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why are you defining one class within another class?

Comment: Original assignment required us to create a class person in a class book. Current program is an extension of that. (I fail to see how a class in a class prevents me from doing what I ask though.)

Comment: Looking at the code, I'd say you failed to grasp how classes are supposed to work. Perhaps it's time to pick up a good C++ book.

Comment: Thankyou for posting the code, that helps us to see the problems you're having, but could you elaborate a little bit on how these classes are intended to be used, what problem they model, and just generally what the *right* solution should be doing?  Then we can help you with an answer that really makes sense.

Comment: You just made God kill another puppy.

Comment: @suszterpatt: or to change the teacher.

Comment: I gave up answering homework questions from users with less then 50 rep. They never come back to rate the answers.

Comment: I'm still here lol. I will give you a rating.

Comment: In the simplest terms I can think of... I am trying to get a pointer in one class to point to another pointer in a different class.

Comment: @Brad: No you're not, that's an implementation detail.  What I want to know is what problem the code solves.  What real world information does it represent.

Comment: It would be more helpful to know what you need to accomplish, e.g. to what purpose are you trying to have pointers point at pointers?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not responding earlier. I am working on what LoadMaster said earlier. "it should provide public accessor functions for doing so."  The problem is I have to make a student record that includes a students name, phone number, and gpa. I have this part complete. Now I am adding a hash table based on the users phone number. I also have completed this section except for telling the hash table where the data is. The last part of my assignment is extra credit so if I get this done in time I might attempt it.

Answer (score 2):

In comments you said:

> In the simplest terms I can think of... I am trying to get a pointer in one class to point to another pointer in a different class.

To answer that question: an inner class has no special relationship to the outer class. For example, a `student` instance within the `book` class has no direct way to access its “containing” class.

To do this you would have to pass a pointer to the containing `book` class into `student`’s constructor and store it in an instance variable within `student`.

However, this has a big caveat: when the `student` instance holds a pointer to the containing `book` class, that pointer could become invalid. For example, if you are storing `book` instances in a container like a `std::vector`, the vector may reallocate memory, invalidating any pointers to `book`s held within the `vector`.

If you can guarantee that the `book` will not be stored in an STL container (or anywhere else where it can get moved) then this approach can work.

I would still reconsider the overall approach as having instances store pointers in this way seems fragile. There could be a composition-based approach that would work.

Comment: Kudos for your managing through this code. It seems like only plausible solution if we dismiss any refactoring, which the code desperately needs.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `friend` is suspect.

Typical object-oriented programming dictates that a linked list container class should only deal with pointers to class objects, and should not know about or deal with anything within the class objects themselves.

If the contained class does need to expose information about itself (i.e., any of its members), it should provide public accessor functions for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what others commented about code, so I won't repeat it and just point to invalid syntax in your code:

```
public:
    student book::*currentRoot = &book::currentRoot;
```

1) the pointer to member is not what you wanted, it should have been:

```
public:
    book::student* book::*currentRoot;
```

2) you cannot assign to non-static member in class definition. It's only allowed for static members of integral type. But you can assign to it somewhere where you have an object:

```
void foo()
{
   linkedList l;
   l.currentRoot = &book::currentRoot;
}
```